# Get XML Node with id or name

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability id="test" name="test">
       <File Path="bin/test.exe" />
       <File Path="bin/abc.dll" />
       <File Path="bin/xyz.dll" />
       <File Path="LICENSE" />
       <File Path="third-party-programs.txt" />
    </Capability>
    <Capability id="test1" name="test1">
       <File Path="bin/test1.exe" />
       <File Path="LICENSE" />
       <File Path="third-party-programs.txt" />
    </Capability>
<Capabilities>
```

I want to get the node with id="test1" but without looping through all the nodes.
I tried using the following in java

```
try {
        documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // get the node with id="test1"
    Node capabilityNode = document.getElementById("test1");
```

From the above code I get null. getElementbyId documentation says that id attribute must have type ID. How can I make sure that id is of type ID or is there a way I can get the node directly without looping by name?

Thanks

Comment: is getElementById is in java?

Comment: yes its in java

Comment: An attribute can be made of type ID by defining for the document a DTD that says so. Otherwise, you'll need to loop.

Comment: How can I do that DTD?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `getElementById` using `XPath`.
This function will return the first element that has attribute `id` with value `idValue`.

```
public static Node getElementById(Document document, String idValue) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    return (Node) xpath.evaluate(String.format("//*[@id='%s']", idValue), document, XPathConstants.NODE);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so first of all you missing closing slash in the last  tag.
second thing is that if you want to get the attributes of some element you can use with the (Element) type which retrive the attributes from the node that you want to
observe. this solution will loop only twice and not through all tags

```
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Capability");
    String nodeAttribute ="";
    for(int i =0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
        nodeAttribute = ((Element) nodeList.item(i)).getAttribute("id");
        if(nodeAttribute.equals("test1"))
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("nodeAttribute:"+nodeAttribute+ " Node 
    Length:"+nodeList.getLength());
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Tag name is `Capability`, `id` is an attribute name.

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake,fixed

Comment: But it's still not what the OP wants. It will just get the list of all the `Capability` elements, while the OP wants an exact `Capability` element with `id="test1"`.